# Can my employer track everything in my mobile even i disconnected my wifi connection?

Tags: appsec, user-tracking, geolocation

Can my employer track everything in my mobile?  I am always connected to wifi while working but disconnect it always after going home. We have an ID whenever we were connected to wifi. Also i installed outlook in my mobile to monitor my work load every night.

Can security engineer track everything in my mobile? Like playing games? Bank online. Specially visiting websites. Messages. Photos and videos? I am afraid he is watching my activities. Also... he mentioned to me that he was able to track the location of my officemate overseas. Imagine he knew that my officemates is in maldives.

So i think he can also see my browsing history. Bank online. Calls. Messages. Etc et

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can my employer see what I do on the internet when I am connected to the company network?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142803/can-my-employer-see-what-i-do-on-the-internet-when-i-am-connected-to-the-company)

Comment: Who owns the phone?  That's a question that really needs to be answered to be able to answer this question.

Comment: @S.L.Barth - read the titles; not the same question at all.

Comment: Is there a mobile device management (MDM) solution installed on the phone?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a company owned device, or if they had you install other software on the phone, then it's very possible. There are a variety of Mobile device management (MDM) software packages that could be installed on the phone. These packages are limited as to what they can do by Apple/Google security models -- assuming they didn't root your phone -- so it's unlikely that they could monitor encrypted traffic from other apps (Banking, website content/login info) but they could probably see your device location and maybe websites visited, calls, messages, etc.

If you could figure out what MDM package it is you could check what permissions it has on the phone.

Also, if you've hooked the phone up to company email (exchange, google for business, etc.) this gives them some ability to remotely control/wipe your phone as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't a company owned device then most likely no. They can only read unencrypted traffic when you are connected to their Wifi (although for encrypted traffic they can see the IP address it is sent to).

In theory you could monitor the mobile traffic and for EDGE / 3G technology it may be feasible to read it. For data sent not over HTTPS it would then be possible to read it. You could also theoretically man in the middle it and force the phone into a less secure protocol - see [Can mobile phone data be intercepted or compromised?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172108/can-mobile-phone-data-be-intercepted-or-compromised/172115#172115).

Man in the middling a mobile connection would be highly illegal in most jurisdictions. The equipment to read unencrypted traffic is not commonplace - I would be surprised to see it used in the workplace.