# How can HTTPS be secure when used over open/cracked WiFi?

Tags: tls, wifi, krack

In the top answer to

- [Consequences of the WPA2 KRACK attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/171356/96753)

it is recommended:

> Generally, use HTTPS for anything that needs to be secure (you should do this anyway, also over ethernet, but especially over Wi-Fi now), use a VPN as an extra layer, etc.

I'm trying to grasp how HTTPS could be secure over a broken transport layer.  Isn't a man-in-the-middle attack possible?  Are there other concerns I'm not thinking about?

**Is HTTPS actually reliable protection when used over open or broken WiFi?**

---

Edit: I'm aware of the math details of asymmetric cryptography.  I'm asking about MITM.  I guess what I was missing is the security aspect of the HTTPS certificates being signed.  In that case, if I'm understanding right, trusting self-signed certificates *and* using WPA2 *would* allow a man-in-the-middle attack?  But if you have a valid list of certificate authorities (a valid way to check the signatures on certs) and you don't trust self-signed certs...then you would be safe?

Comment: You aren't getting the certificate from the WiFi access point, right? So why would it affect it? :) What you'd have to watch out for are HTTPS downgrade attacks such as SSL Strip. HSTS helps prevent this.

Comment: the reason we encrypt is to protect the communication over untrusted networks ....

Comment: @schroeder, please see edit.

Comment: Effectively, the entire point of HTTPS is to protect against a man-in-the-middle on an otherwise insecure network.  If you do anything to subvert the requirements of HTTPS, such as trusting certs for which you have no valid basis to trust, than a man-in-the-middle attack is possible.

Comment: fwiw, wired Ethernet is "wide open" in this respect as well, but you don't see lot of panic

Comment: @dandavis, yeah, I'm not worried about someone patching into my cat5 cables.

Comment: In any case, the question is KRACK-agnostic and even Wifi-agnostic. The question is about MITM.